# Replacing characters in a string - am I correct?

Tags: php

I need to confirm that I am using the best method in php.  looking at other posts, there appears to be alternative methods.  My knowledge of php is not great, hence the question.

```
$commalist17    =  (str_replace('<br />', ',', $data['record']['field_17_value']));
```

where $data['record']['field_17_value'] is

`something<br />another<br />and again<br />last one`

then displaying $commalist17 in the page.

The field might be anything up to 20 items long with `<br />` between each one.

Comment: Did you try it? What results did you get?

Comment: `str_replace` is the recommended method for non-regex approaches.  The extra parenthesis you have around it aren't needed, though.  But as John said, test -- it's the best way to know if it works for you.

Comment: As song says "simply th best" - your solution is correct for requirement explained

Comment: sorry - yes it did work, but was not sure if I was using the correct or best method. Trying to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that string will always have `<br />` and not just `<br>` or `<br/>` then your approach is fine enough. In real world though it is quite likelly that you will meet different notation of `br` tag. Mind `str_replace` accepts array as 1st argument too so

```
$commalist17 = (str_replace(array('<br />', '<br/>', '<br>'), ',', $data['record']['field_17_value']));
```

might be more fault-proof.

Is it possible that you can have cut `<br />` in line ending? You could validate this too.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I suppose a <br /> at the end might be possible. Essentially the data may appear in more than one location and so needs to be flexible. My next task is to learn to count the number of words or characters and then show the data in different locations if it is too long. All good fun :)